# how to do mutiple needles in a haystack check in php code

Tags: php

i am trying to check for mutpile  different words in a string in php

'in stock' would run threw check and be ok

i was just wondering how to check for say 5 needles at the same time, instead of just one as shown in code below

`$InStock` - the variable feeding into this code could be any of these follow values

1. In Stock --  i would not check for this value --
2. Temporaily out of stock
3. Available from these sellers
4. Only 5 left in stock
5. Usually dispacthed within
6. In stock on

how can i simply do something like this

```
$needle = "Temporaily out of stock" && "Available from these sellers" && "left in stock" && "Usually dispacthed within" && "In stock on";
```

thanks

```
    //in stock error check
    $InStock_data = $InStock;
    $haystack = strtolower($InStock_data);
    $needle = "out of stock";

    $InStock_site_check = strpos($haystack,$needle);
    if($InStock_site_check === false) {
     // string needle NOT found in haystack - ok / in stock 
        $InStock_error = '';

    }
    else {
     // string needle found item is temp out of stock / not sold or error
        $currentprice_doubled = ($currentpricecheck * 2);
        $currentprice_tripled = ($currentpricecheck * 3);
        if (empty($currentprice_doubled)) {
            $currentprice_doubled = ($oldpricedouble * 2);
            $currentprice_tripled = ($oldpricedouble * 3);
        }
            $InStock_error = "Stock error found - do some code here";
            // put warning row in here  $warningrow = 'class="danger"';
    }
```

Comment: I think you mean || instead of &&, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one of the possible approaches:

```
$needle = 'Temporaily out of stock|Available from these sellers|left in stock|Usually dispacthed within|In stock on';
if (preg_match('/'.$needle.'/', $haystack)) // if true - item is OUT of stock
```

Comment: thanks this simple solution works well for my problem